# Why does conv2() returns a white image instead of a filtered image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In Matlab, I created a 5x5 gaussian kernel with `fspecial()`. I assigned the kernel to a variable called `h`. I read in an image through `imread()` and assigned the image to a variable called `Im`.

The image has some random noise on it and my intention is to see how I can remove the noise. Now, I want to convolute the image `Im` with the kernel `h`. I tried to use the function `conv2()` this way: `conv2(Im, h);`

But it turns out that I get an empty white picture when I do a `imshow()`. I expected the result to be a blurred version of the image `Im` after convoluting with the kernel `h`.

This is what I did:

```
>> Im = imread('image.jpg');
>> h = fspecial('gaussian', 5, 1.0);
>> C1 = conv2(Im, h);
```

I tried the same process with other pictures and I get an empty white picture when I do `imshow()` too. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try `imagesc`. Besides, how is the _content_ of both Im and C1?

Comment: @Hugues You meant 'imagesc', right?

Comment: The proper function is `imfilter`. With `conv2` you may need to think about the channels.

Comment: @Hugues Thanks, now with `imagesc`, I could see the image again. But the image is shown with some kind of inverted "rainbow" like effect. I thought the gaussian filter should make the picture look blurry or remove noise instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are working on a `uint8` type image. In this case the filtering might saturate the pixels' values and cause artifacts. Try:

```
Im = im2double( imread( 'image.jpg' ) );
h = fspecial( 'gaussian', 5, 1.0 );
C1 = imfilter( Im, h );
figure; imshow( C1, [] ); title( 'filtered image' );
```

PS
I'm not sure about it, but I think that when reading `Im` as `uint8` you have values in range [0..255], after `conv2` you have `double` values in roughly the same range. However, `image` saturates pixels (for `double` images) at 1 (not 255), and this is the reason for the totally white image you see.

Answer (score 0):

The white image is because you have not done normalization.
After you conv2 your image with C1 = conv2(Im, h), in maplab if you check the C1 variable you will find the values are very high.

To normalize your image divide the image by 255 and perform imshow. 
imshow(c1/255);